# Store the Attachment in the File folder and remove from the SharePoint List Item?

Tags: splistitem, updatelistitems

I have a requirement that when an item is added

Store the Attachment in the File folder
Remove the Attachment from the SharePoint List Item

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Are you using SharePoint online?

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box, this is not really easy to do (only if you are good at programming). You can however use a custom tool like **Plumsail Workflow actions pack**. I have used it before so I know it contains this specific workflow action, however, the tool is pretty expensive.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out, will update the post with the solution shortly.